# C# button not returning expected value

Tags: c#

I have a windows ATM app and I'm stuck on this part:

I have `pin` and `firstName` as private strings and balance as private double.

However, when I try to display the balance in the text area, it just prints `0`. Is it because `retrieveAccountInformation()` has void as the return? How can I change my code so that I can use `pin`, `firstName`, and `balance` in my other methods?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SQLDll;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication14
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Connection myConnection;
    private Statement myStatement;
    private ResultSet myResultSet;

    String databaseURL = "http://www.boehnecamp.com/phpMyAdmin/razorsql_mysql_bridge.php";
    public string pin, firstName, userAccountNumber;
    public double balance;
    public double withdraw = 0;
    public double deposit = 0;
    bool buttonClicked;
    bool buttonClicked2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            //connect to database
            SQL sql = new SQL();
            myConnection = sql.getConnection(databaseURL);
            //create Statement for executing SQL
            myStatement = myConnection.createStatement(databaseURL);
            loadAccountNumbers();
            updateBalance();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to database server");
        }
        //close statement and database connection 
       myStatement.close();
       myConnection.close();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void setText(string text)
    {


    }
    //load account numbers to ComboBox
    private void loadAccountNumbers()
    {
        //get all account numbers from database
        try
        {
            myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT accountNumber FROM accountInformation");
            // add account numbers to ComboBox
            while (myResultSet.next())
            {
                accountNumberComboBox.Items.Add(myResultSet.getString("accountNumber"));
            }
            myResultSet.close(); // close myResultSet
        }//end try
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in loadAccountNumbers");
        }
    }//end method to loadAccountNumbers

    private void retrieveAccountInformation()
    {
        //get account info
        try
        {
            myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT pin, " +
           "firstName, balanceAmount FROM accountInformation " +
           "WHERE accountNumber = '" + userAccountNumber + "'");

            //get next result
            if (myResultSet.next())
            {
                pin = myResultSet.getString("pin");
                firstName = myResultSet.getString("firstName");
                balance = myResultSet.getDouble("balanceAmount");
            }
            myResultSet.close(); //close myResultSet
        }//end try
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in retrieveAccountInformation");
        }
    }// end method retrieveAccountInformation

    //update database after withdrawing
    private void updateBalance()
    {
        //update balance in database
        try
        {
            myStatement.executeUpdate("UPDATE accountInformation" +
                           " SET balanceAmount = " + balance + " WHERE " +
                           "accountNumber = '" + userAccountNumber + "'");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in updateBalace");
        }
    }//end method updateBalance

    private void accountNumberComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        accountNumberComboBox.Enabled = false;
        numberTextField.Text = " ";
        messageTextArea.Text = "Enter your PIN #.";
        button0.Enabled = true;
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
        button4.Enabled = true;
        button5.Enabled = true;
        button6.Enabled = true;
        button7.Enabled = true;
        button8.Enabled = true;
        button9.Enabled = true;
        buttonDone.Enabled = true;
        retrieveAccountInformation();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("1");
        numberTextField.Text += "1";
        buttonEnter.Enabled = true;

    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("2");
        numberTextField.Text += "2";
        buttonEnter.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("3");
        numberTextField.Text += "3";
        buttonEnter.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("4");
        numberTextField.Text += "4";
        buttonEnter.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("5");
        numberTextField.Text += "5";
        buttonEnter.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("6");
        numberTextField.Text += "6";
        buttonEnter.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("7");
        numberTextField.Text += "7";
        buttonEnter.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("8");
        numberTextField.Text += "8";
        buttonEnter.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("9");
        numberTextField.Text += "9";
        buttonEnter.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setText("0");
        numberTextField.Text += "0";
        buttonEnter.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void buttonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            numberTextField.Text = " ";
            buttonEnter.Enabled = false;
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = false;
            button4.Enabled = false;
            button5.Enabled = false;
            button6.Enabled = false;
            button7.Enabled = false;
            button8.Enabled = false;
            button9.Enabled = false;
            button0.Enabled = false;
            buttonBalance.Enabled = true;
            buttonWithdraw.Enabled = true;
            buttonDeposit.Enabled = true;
            messageTextArea.Text = "Welcome," + firstName;
            updateBalance();
           if (buttonClicked == true)
            {
                withdraw = Double.Parse(numberTextField.Text);
                balance = balance - withdraw;
                updateBalance();
            }

    }

    private void buttonBalance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        retrieveAccountInformation();
        updateBalance();

        messageTextArea.Text=(balance.ToString());
        //display balance to messageTextArea
    }

    private void buttonWithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonBalance.Enabled = false;
        buttonWithdraw.Enabled = false;
        button0.Enabled = true;
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
        button4.Enabled = true;
        button5.Enabled = true;
        button6.Enabled = true;
        button7.Enabled = true;
        button8.Enabled = true;
        button9.Enabled = true;
        messageTextArea.Text = "Enter withdrawal amount:";
        buttonClicked = true;

    }

    private void buttonDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        button4.Enabled = false;
        button5.Enabled = false;
        button6.Enabled = false;
        button7.Enabled = false;
        button8.Enabled = false;
        button9.Enabled = false;
        button0.Enabled = false;
        buttonEnter.Enabled = false;
        buttonBalance.Enabled = false;
        buttonWithdraw.Enabled = false;
        buttonDone.Enabled = false;
        buttonDeposit.Enabled = false;
        accountNumberComboBox.Enabled = true;
        messageTextArea.Text = "Please select your account number.";


    }

    private void buttonDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonBalance.Enabled = false;
        buttonWithdraw.Enabled = false;
        button0.Enabled = true;
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
        button4.Enabled = true;
        button5.Enabled = true;
        button6.Enabled = true;
        button7.Enabled = true;
        button8.Enabled = true;
        button9.Enabled = true;
        messageTextArea.Text = "Enter deposit amount:";
        buttonClicked2 = true;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is balance declared? Have you stepped through your code with the debugger and checked the balance equals what you expect after you step over where it's assigned?

Comment: I tried adding retrieveAccountInfo(); into my buttonBalance_click method as well, but that didn't change anything. It still displays 0.

Comment: If it displays 0 then balance must be 0, since that is what is getting put into your messageTextArea textbox. It's diificult to help without knowing what updateBalance() does... as Simon said, step through the code and look at your call stack to make sure you are executing the methods in the correct order.

Comment: All I have in my code is private double balance in my public partial class form1, and then the line balance=myResultSet.getDouble("balanceAmount"); in the retrieve method

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see if `balance=myResultSet.getDouble("balanceAmount");` gets a non-0 value?

Comment: No, do I need to put a breakpoint on that line? and then run my program and see what happens?

Comment: yes, assuming you are using VisualStudio, you would set a breakpoint on that line, then run with debugging (F5 key by default). When it stops on that line, it hasn't actually run yet. you need to do 1 step to execute it (by pressing F10, or clicking the 'step over' button). Then hovering the mouse over `balance` should show its value, or right-click the variable name `balance` and in the context menu choose "quick watch". You might also want to read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: On another note, your code looks like `myResultSet` and `myStatement` might also be class-wide variables. In C#, best practice is to declare variables as close to their use as possible. Methods should also try not to share variables as mush as possible. Anyway, those 2 variables should probably be declared inside the `retrieveAccountInformation` function, that way they are made unavailable and eventually garbage collected, and there is no chance that other functions in the same class mess up those variables that this method is dependent on.

Comment: I went ahead and posted the rest of my code. I am still learning all of this stuff so it's hard for me to explain, let alone understand some of this stuff. Should I declare those variables in each method instead?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `myResultSet.next()`.

If you have two SQL Statements, eg

```sql
SELECT * FROM Users  
Go  
SELECT * FROM Accounts  
Go
```

`if (myResultSet.next())` -> this will read the data returned from the second SQL Statement.

I think this maybe what you are wanting:

```cs
string connString = AppConfigurationManager.GetAppSetting("ConnectionString",IsQA);
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT pin, " +
"firstName, balanceAmount FROM accountInformation " +
"WHERE accountNumber = '" + userAccountNumber + "'", conn))
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        try
        {
            dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                pin = dr.getString("pin");
                firstName = dr.getString("firstName");
                balance = dr.getDouble("balanceAmount");
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        //clean up resources that access Data
        if (dr != null)
        {
            dr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, the part of the code that you changed is what was actually given to me by my professor.. so Im assuming he wants me to stick with what he gave me

Answer (score 0):

you can using "out" or "ref" in my opinion

```
private void retrieveAccountInformation(out string pin, out string firstname, out double balance)
{
    //get account info
    try
    {
        myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT pin, " +
       "firstName, balanceAmount FROM accountInformation " +
       "WHERE accountNumber = '" + userAccountNumber + "'");
        //get next result
        if (myResultSet.next())
        {
            pin = myResultSet.getString("pin");
            firstName = myResultSet.getString("firstName");
            balance = myResultSet.getDouble("balanceAmount");
        }
        myResultSet.close(); //close myResultSet
    }//end try
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in retrieveAccountInformation");
    }
}// end method retrieveAccountInformation

private void buttonBalance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pin = "";
    string firstname = "";
    double balance = 0;

    retrieveAccountInformation(out string pin, out string firstname, out double balance);

    updateBalance();
    messageTextArea.Text=(balance.ToString());
    //display balance to messageTextArea
}
```

Comment: no overload method retrieveAccountInfo takes 0 arguments is the first

Comment: you must call the retrieveAccountInformation with same parameter. Probably you had call retrieveAccountInformation with no parameter. Of course it gave you error, because the method have three parameter now..please see my example in buttonBalance_Click that i wrote before..

Comment: ohhh my fault..just remove the type data when call retrieveAccountInformation..just wrote like this retrieveAccountInformation(out pin, out firstname, out balance);

Comment: now the only error is "identifier expected" after pin, firstName and balance

Comment: just use "ref", dont "out". out keyword need assigned default value. if you want to using "out" you must assigned defaule value. If you dont want to assigned default value, you should using "ref". Oh you should look at the parameter name should "firstName", and you must assigned default value outside try-catch statement. Hope it will answer your problem

Answer (score -1):

Because pin, firstName, balance is Local Variable and this method is private void so if you want to get value from a void method. Use in,out variable. This make a method can return multiple value

Morever, what updateBalance() do ? It declared varial and call retrieveAccountInformation method ????

Example :

```
private void retrieveAccountInformation(out string pin,out string firstname,out double balance)
{
 //get account info
 try
 {
        myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT pin, " +
       "firstName, balanceAmount FROM accountInformation " +
       "WHERE accountNumber = '" + userAccountNumber + "'");

        //get next result
        if (myResultSet.next())
        {
            pin = myResultSet.getString("pin");
            firstName = myResultSet.getString("firstName");
            balance = myResultSet.getDouble("balanceAmount");
        }
        myResultSet.close(); //close myResultSet
    }//end try
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in retrieveAccountInformation");
    }
}// end method retrieveAccountInformation

private void buttonBalance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string pin, firstname;
    double balance;
    retrieveAccountInformation(pin, firstname, balance);
    messageTextArea.Text=(balance.ToString());
    //display balance to messageTextArea
}
```

Comment: those  variables are declared as class-wide, they are not private to that method (otherwise that code wouldn't compile)

Comment: I didn't down vote you but the pin, firstName, balance are Member  Variables, there scope can't Local.

Comment: Ok, I agree. I didn't know that but he call a void method without return any value so how that class-wide variables can get new value